# Can a project be made fom an existing RDL file?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a number of RDL files I crated a while back, but I no longer have the project files. Is there a ways to use the RDL files in a new project? I did some nice formatting in the reports that I would like to reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Visual Studio to create a new Project.  Then I would right-click the Reports node in the Solution Explorer and choose Add Existing Item.